# How to match make others?

Tags: society, relationships, dating

I'm writing a story about few foreigners doing a work stint on a small island country, ~500K. The country is quite similar to the western world except dating is mandatory for every single person, with a few exceptions like you are too old, sick, your spouse died recently etc.

The mandatory dating is explained as a local custom and serves as a plot device. The custom stems from local belief that single people are incomplete and they should couple up. However since they have free will to decide singles can't be forced but they must show that they try. Something like the way that trying to find a job shows that you are not too lazy to work and that you really want a job.

My story is about the psychological effects of pressure to couple up. The mood is similar to Lost in translation.

There's a dating app where every citizen has an account, which lists the chronological information about that person. Like pictures from childhood till present year, schools you attended, places you lived, jobs you had etc.

There are three phases that recur one after the other which last 1 month each. First phase men ask women, second phase women ask men (like Bumble), third phase 3rd parties match make users.

I need some idea how should matchmaking work. In real world you might play matchmaker between friends, family or maybe colleagues i.e. people you know quite well. But you can't infer much from profile.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding. Your question is problematic because we are missing quite a lot of information that is needed for us to answer. The biggest things missing are ***Why* is dating mandatory? What is the *purpose* of this compulsion?**.

Comment: @MichaelK It's a local custom that has been always like that in the country. Everybody must either abide by it or leave the place.  Basically the premise of my story is about few foreigners forced to cope with it.

Comment: That did not answer my questions. Why? And what is the **purpose**? You are going to have a really hard time maintaining any kind of credibility and willing suspension of disbelief if the only reason you mention for this strange custom is to say "It's just because we have always done it this way".

Comment: @MichaelK It's a plot device. I want to tell a story about mandatory dating, and this setting serves me well. I know is kinda silly, but its no more silly then warp engines, killer birds or having sex with aliens.

Comment: This setup sounds enough like Plato's _Republic_ that you probably ought to read it first (or at least Jo Walton's novel based on it, _The Just City_).

Comment: @Chibi It can be a plot device for the sake of the story, but for our sake and ability to answer your question, you have to treat this like a piece of your world with a concrete reason behind it. What part of the culture made this so? How did this custom come about and why is it still followed? That's what we need to be able to help you better.

Comment: @Chibi Well we still cannot answer the question because if we do not know the **purpose** of this mandatory dating, then we cannot figure out what the people behind the app has set as the parameters for matchmaking. Without that kind of information, the app just becomes Compulsory Tinder where people match on whatever they want with the only solid information to match on is age, gender and location, and subjective matching is on looks and the presentation text... but now with the backend throwing some random matches your way. And what is the punishment for not going on a date?

Comment: If you just want to know how dating apps work you can read up.  https://medium.com/shakuro/how-dating-apps-work-22ef39c7698b  Of course the internal algorithm for each is proprietary but the general approach of these programs (and there are many) is easy to learn about.

Comment: @MichaelK Basically country hates singles. I haven't planned to explain the punishments. But they are severe enough for people to not fool enough. For foreigners its expulsion and they are banned from future entry.

Comment: @Chibi So what kind of relationships are formed from this? People will not automatically fall in love just because they get mashed together like a couple of Deuterium atoms... there need to be some significant heat between them before they fuse. Is there a requirement that "You must get **serious** with this matching, or else!"?

Comment: @MichaelK Its not about relationship its about the expectations. The society expects from you to try to find your love, soulmate, partner and you are not able to opt out. Basically you **MUST** spend some time every month to dating the same as you must spend some time every year preparing your taxes, having a shower every day, or brush your teeth etc. It's OK if you don't click and you don't like your current date, but you must try.

Comment: @Chibi So the **purpose** is "Find true love". Wish you would have just said it from the start. Answer: match on anything, everything, nothing. There is no recipe for true love.

Comment: What's the tech level?  Why wouldn't duplicating the rules used by online match making sites like eHarmony work (they'd likely work better than what you've suggested in your Q).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the Orthodox Jewish tradition of [Shidduch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shidduch), which involves professional match makers who assist young adults in finding mates using such factors as character, status level, education and financial resources.

You might also want to look at the Orthodox Jewish [view of marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_views_on_marriage) (specifically in the area of Family Purity) for answers to the issues which are being asked in the comments.  Your government's motivations for requiring dating might be parallel those views.

Answer (score 2):

I hope (dare I hope?) you are writing a romantic comedy.  This would not be about how the government's dating app would work but about how the wily foreigners game the system.

You can have the government app match people semi randomly for reasons that seem appropriate for a government - family history of genetic diseases, or similar work history etc.  The foreigners hack the code and figure how to insert profile variables that insure that the same man and woman get put together each time.  These individuals in the foreigner community are friends anyway and that way they do not need to go on a lot of uncomfortable dates with weirdos.

Of course one such couple falls in love.  Another winds up on a date with a local anyway, but one whose profile somehow matches the hack that the foreigns have put in place - how did that happen?

Comment: Actually it's about the dread of modern dating market meat grinder where you can't just opt out.

Comment: That works too.  Same answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the third phase and obviously are incapable of finding a match, you have to answer questions about yourself.

Those questions range from banal characteristics (e.g. your favourite food, music, ...) over your job (field of work, income, work ethics, ...) to your political views (do you oppose/support gay marriage, your views on environment protection, do you believe in public health care, ...)

Whenever someone thinks, a relevant characteristic is not included in the catalogue, it is added. So over the time there have been assembled a *lot* of questions. Some of them pretty stupid or obscure.

You don't have to answer all the questions, but the more questions you answer, the more determined you appear. You also don't have to answer all questions at once. Most people have already answered some questions over the time and just update them, when something changes. If you're in phase 3, it is considered appropriate, to answer at least an additional question once a week.

While computer algorithms can match, how close two people are in the questions, it is considered a fine art, to study profiles and get "a feeling" for the people behind those questions and guess, when different answers make potential partners more interesting for each other and where similar answers are needed for more sympathy.